# How to stream data structure or record through NetworkStream?

Tags: .net, tcpclient, networkstream, delphi-prism, tcpserver

I have the following data structure or record, which I need to stream to and from another machine through NetworkStream.

```
  TRemoteRecord = record
    command:TRemoteCommand;
    status:TRemoteStatus;
    signame:string;
    rvalue:double;
    ivalue:LongInt;
  end;
```

This is the way I am sending or writing data structure or record to the stream.

```
TheStream:NetworkStream;
 SignalClient:TcpClient;
 SignalServer:TcpServer;
 sb:TRemoteRecord;

 SignalClient.ConnectNew(LocalIPEdit.Text,Int32.Parse(ClientPort.Text));
 TheStream := new NetWorkStream(SignalClient.Connect.DataSocket);
 TheStream.Write(sb, 0 SizeOf(sb));
```

When I compile it, it raises an exception, "There is no overloaded write with these parameters."

How do you send and receive data structure or record through networkstream?

Thanks,

Comment: sb is not an array of bytes (bytes[]), so the exception is raised.
i.e. NetworkStream.Write(bytes[] buffer, int offset, int size).

I think you need to serialize your record to a byte array first.
This may not be straightforward, as your Record contains various types and a string type (getting a size of string which is of variable length needs special attention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize your Record first to a byte[].

This will get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx

Here are two methods to serialize and deserialize a given type:
http://dooba.net/2009/07/02/c-sharp-and-serializing-byte-arrays/
[NB: Pay special attention to how you handle the string (it has variable size) and your custom types.]

Comment: I did implement datacontractserializer. Although compiler compiled successfully, it didn't work. In fact, it was worse. The deserialized string data was empty. Plus, the deserialized double and Integer data were completely either wrapped around or was not the right values.

Comment: Try another means to serialize. Did you try http://dooba.net/2009/07/02/c-sharp-and-serializing-byte-arrays/ approach?
I used this to stream a struct through NetworkStream successfully. As I said above, your record is complex given the custom DataTypes and you have a string (so you need to get the actual string size). Give this other approach a try with a simpler struct so you have peace of mind it works. Then hack your way through the more complex record you have.